# Start android emulator without starting Android Studio for flutter applications

Tags: android-emulator, flutter

Is it possible to start emulator in such a way `flutter doctor` detects it and `flutter run` should able to deploy to flutter code ?

I tried `emulator -avd *image name*` but `flutter doctor` fails to detect running emulator and flutter run does not deploys code on emulator.

Comment: can you try `adb kill-server` and check if it recognizes them afterwards? Also check if `adb devices` lists the emulator.

Answer (score 5):

In notepad type the following and save it as "file_name.bat" and run it:

```
SET builddir=%~dp0
SET EX="C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe"
CALL %EX%  -avd emu_name -partition-size 512 -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform
pause
```

emu_name is the name of your emulator.

Answer (score 2):

first you must change directory of your command line to `${android_SDK_DIR}\emulator`
most of the time its in `c:\users\${yourUserName}\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\`
and run `emulator -list-avds` and it show you your emulator that you create before in android studio then just run `emulator @${your emulator name that shows on the list}` for example  `emulator @Nexus6_API_27`

remember that maybe your android sdk folder directory was change on install SDK and if you don't create emulator in android studio before , the list will be empty so before you run command you must create AVD in your android studio

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an adb issue, not of the Flutter doctor issue. Because if adb is running perfectly then it would show you a list of devices from android studio or from flutter devices or by running a `adb devices` command.

You can try restarting adb using commands:

- `adb kill-server` and
- then `adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method I found is you just go to cmd

```
flutter emulator -- launch <emulator id
```

it will run and will be detected by your intelli j

Answer (score 0):

I have to get an answer in here somehow, even if it's to offer that the command may also be plural. Yes, indeed, you can run "flutter emulators" from your flutter\bin directory (if you haven't added to system PATH yet) and voila...

> PS C:> flutter emulators 1 available emulator:
>
> Pixel_2_API_28 • pixel_2 • Google • Pixel 2 API 28
>
> To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch '. To
>   create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.
>
> You can find more information on managing emulators at the links
>   below:   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager